# TFS (high level) install process

Tags: tfs, installation, visual-sourcesafe, vssconverter

Can someone explain the high level process, of installing TFS?  I've had the Server set up by a "network guy".  It's TFS 2010, and we're using VS 2010 and moving to VS 2012.  Do I need to install something on my client machine, or does Visual Studio just "hook" into TFS automatically?

Also, I've been tasked with moving our VSS to TFS.  I've seen those posts and don't need coverage of that, unless you wanted to point me to the best links of how to.  When those instructions mention installing Team Explorer or needing SQL Server Express on the machine you are doing the migration on, do they mean my workstation or the Server?

The Microsoft walk-throughs are the worse (IMHO)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, I followed http://tfsguide.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20To%20-%20Migrate%20Source%20Code%20to%20Team%20Foundation%20Server%20from%20Visual%20Source%20Safe

And nearly got it installed.  I'll post a new question with the new issue.